# can not detect image in java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, path, imageicon

i want to make a simple Widget that has a combobox that can change picture.
i have 2 png picture in src/test (beside my .java files)

when i run my program i receive this exceptions :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at first.gui.<init>(gui.java:11)
at first.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

and this is my codes:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class gui extends JFrame {

    JLabel lb = new JLabel();
    Icon[] pics = {
        new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("f.png")),
        new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("i.png"))
    };
    String[] str = {
        "f.png", "i.png"
    };

    JComboBox box = new JComboBox(str);

    public gui() {

        super("title");

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        box.addItemListener(
            new ItemListener() {
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {


                    if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)

                        lb.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);
                }
            });
        add(box);
    }
}
```

what should i do to solve it?

Comment: _Eclipse can not detect image path_ It's not Eclipse. It's your java program.

Comment: See [tag:embedded-resource] under _learn more_.

Comment: Did you add `src/test` to your `classpath`?

Comment: yes i add getClass().getResource("/src/test/f.png") and still not work

Comment: `classpath`, the path the JVM will look in for stuff. It's a ENV variable or setting in Eclipse under the `Run configuration`.

Comment: i have checked it and yes test was in classpath

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230). Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done this and it makes my code write

the only thing that i should do is :

putting my images in

```
project_name/bin/test
```

where my .class files are
after that it can recognize the source

Answer (score 2):

With the problem as you describe it relative path should be `./src/test/f.png` (eclipse starts the application from the relative `$project_loc`, which is the root folder for your project)

Consider instead using a resources folder eg. `src/resources/` or `lib/` for your images/other resources.

Comment: so you mean i should make another folder then put image in it and again run?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. And update the paths inside your program. Best if you stick them in `static final` fields.

Answer (score 1):

You use a relative path `"f.png"`, and the class is in package (directory) `first`. So use `"/test/f.png"`. *(And be sure everything is case-sensite.)*

Comment: Open the produced jar, with 7zip/WinZip or so, and check the directories. The directory `src/test` normally is for unit tests, so place the images in src/resources or so.